# plot negative binomial linear regressor

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

if I generate data for a linear model like this:

```
N <- 1000
sd <- 1
b0 <- -0.5
b1 <- 0.4
x <- seq(1, 10, length.out = N)
y <- rnorm(N, mean = b0 + x * b1)
```

I can nicely plot the linear relationship

```
plot(x, y)
```

[image]

How do I have to transfer the data to plot something like this for a negative binomial model.

```
y2 <- rnbinom(N, size = sd, mu = exp(b0 + x * b1))
plot(x, y2)
```

[image]

How can I plot the linear relationship there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linear relation in your data is due to your parameterization

```
mu = exp(b0 + x * b1)
```

Since you are taking `exp` of the linear part,  you need to take $ln(y2)$ to see the line. `plot` in R has logarithmic scales built in, so we can get a plot of the data that demonstrates the linear relationship just by plotting y2 on a $ln$ scale and then adding the line for mu.

```
plot(x, y2, log = "y")
mu = exp(b0 + x * b1)
lines(x,mu)
```

[image: y2 data on a logarithmic scale]

Of course, since you are only generating integers with rnbinom,  the output is discretized in the y direction.  That was true on the original graph, but the scale made it hard to see. You can see the discretization in the original plot by changing the plot character  `plot(x, y2, pch=".")` and even more by restricting the range of y-values displayed    `plot(x, y2, pch=".", ylim=c(0,40))`

The log-scale graph shows the discretization and also shows how the noise distributes about the line in x-ln(y) space.